# Way to pass and receive $(this) as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing, this

Say I have two images and two divs.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img id="div0image" class='divImages' alt="" src="../images/div0image.png" />
        <img id="div1image" class='divImages' alt="" src="../images/div1image.png" />

        <div id="div0" class='divs'></div>
        <div id="div1" class='divs'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Assume the CSS is this

```
#div0, #div1, #div0image, #div1image {
    width: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Now, say I have a Javascript function like this

```
function somethingIsClicked(thisParameter) { //thisParameter needs to be a $(this) object
    var thisID = $(this).attr('id'); //$(this) should refer to the object passed in the parameter (thisParameter)

    $(this).addClass('checkIfThisClassIsAdded');
    alert('works!');
}
```

And then suppose I have these two functions

```
$('.divs').click( function() {
    somethingIsClicked($(this));
});

$('.divImages').click( function() {
    thisID = $(this).attr('id'); //div0image
    thisDivsID = thisID.slice(0,4); //div0
    $('#' + thisDivsID).each( function() {
        somethingIsClicked($(this));
    });
```

Is there a correct way to pass and then receive $(this) as a parameter, And Then refer to the $(this) object in the function which received $(this) as a parameter?

Comment: P.S. `#div0, div1, div0image, div1image` should be `#div0, #div1, #div0image, #div1image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Use a parameter

```
$('.divImages').click( function() {
    thisID = $(this).attr('id'); //div0image
    thisDivsID = thisID.slice(0,4); //div0
    $('#' + thisDivsID).each( function() {
        somethingIsClicked($(this));
    });

$('.divs').click( function() {
    somethingIsClicked($(this));
});

function somethingIsClicked(element) {
    var thisID = element.attr('id);
    element.addClass('checkIfThisClassIsAdded');
    alert('works!');
}
```

Or use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to change the context of a function:

```
$('.divImages').click( function() {
    thisID = $(this).attr('id'); //div0image
    thisDivsID = thisID.slice(0,4); //div0
    $('#' + thisDivsID).each( function() {
        somethingIsClicked.call(this);
    });

$('.divs').click( function() {
    somethingIsClicked.call(this);
});

function somethingIsClicked() {
    var thisID = $(this).attr('id);
    $(this).addClass('checkIfThisClassIsAdded');
    alert('works!');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use `.call`.

```
somethingIsClicked.call(this)
```

Optionally, you can pass additional parameters to it, such as the event object:

```
$('.divs').click( function(event) {
    somethingIsClicked.call(this,event);
});
```

Or if you have an array of parameters, .apply works the same way.

```
$('.divs').click( function(event) {
    somethingIsClicked.apply(this,[event,{foo:"Hello World!"}]);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Note however, in this simplified case, it would make more sense to do

```
$('.divs').click(somethingIsClicked);
```

Comment: Okay, so instead of doing "somethingIsClicked($(this));", I should do "somethingIsClicked().call(this);" and then shoud my 'somethingIsClicked' function just be "function somethingIsClicked() { var thisID = $(this).attr('id'); }" with no parameter and that would work? Ah okay, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You typed it wrong @user2719875. As Kevin showed above, `somethingIsClicked.call(this);` not `somethingIsClicked().call(this)` but otherwise yes!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.call(thisParamter, arg1, arg2, arg3 ...)`  or `.apply(thisParamter, [arg1, arg2, ... ])`.

```
$('.divs').click( function() {
    somethingIsClicked.call(this);
});
```

If you don't have other arguments to pass you can use directly:

```
$('.divs').click(somethingIsClicked)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$.proxy`:

```
$('#' + thisDivsID).each( function() {
    $.proxy(somethingIsClicked, this)();
});
```

Your receiving function would then not need any parameters, as `this` would be within the same scope as the `each()` block:

```
function somethingIsClicked() {
    var thisID = $(this).attr('id');    
    $(this).addClass('checkIfThisClassIsAdded');
    alert('works!');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Zx6MN/)

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, you can use

`call(this, arg1,arg2)` 
or 
`apply(this, arrayOfArgs)`

See the link below for a explanation of the differences! 
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx